# No hosted zone found with ID error when deploying

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I am using aws-cdk to create my infrastructure. I'm using using the following code to lookup my hosted zone:

```
const zone = route53.HostedZone.fromLookup(this, 'Zone', { domainName: domainName });
```

When I deploy, I get the following error

```
Failed to create resource. No hosted zone found with ID:xxxxxxxxxxx
```

I have only one hosted zone in route-53 and the ID which the above error is displaying isn't the ID of my Hosted zone. Not sure where it is getting this value from.

Comment: Hi @KaiBurjack, Yes, because it successfully creates some other resources in the correct account, and I also just did a quick recheck. So to answer your question, I am using the correct identity to call the CDK.

Comment: @kaiBurjack Yes, I did and had seen the same issue you pointed to. I was able to figure out what the issue was. Turns out, my cdk.context.json file had the old domain ID, so every time I deployed it was looking for the old domain ID. But thanks for your help.

Comment: Lol ! Hadn't seen your recent comment till I typed my response in !!

Comment: you should put your comment abopu8t the `cdk.context.json` as an answer and accept it as it just helped me! I couldn't work out why I could no longer create my stack and from you post I learnt that that CDK caches lookup values in this file. [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/context.html)

Answer (score 3):

As the comments say above, just deleting the `cdk.context.json` worked for me.

Comment: Need add some supporting information